# (limit) in mongodb aggregration

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$limit :  0}])
```

if we are passing zero it is showing error, with alert a message provide positive value. how can I get all the documents in mongodb Aggregation by giving limit object or any different idea in mongodb aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit at least 1.  If you limit 0, might as well just say `const foo = []`.

For all documents, just do `find({})`.  Or use `aggregate` without a `match`.

Comment: Thanks for answering,  I have 30 line of mongodb query in which I am passing limit.so how can I get all the documents without repeating mongodb query again in which I will get all documents.

Comment: Can you check the limit before you send query, and return empty array if it is zero, otherwise forward it to mongodb?

Comment: I am expanding the fields with lookup and doing many more things. if I am not passing the limit means I want all the documents ( with required fields) in that collection to export as csv file. So that is purpose of doing that.

Comment: You get all the documents by not adding the limit statement.